# Ruby : Cannot load such file --ruby2d (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, visual-studio-code, rubygems

I'm new to Ruby,Writing some code to make a game,so using ruby2d library.

Got an error while writing some basic code.

Help me out Folks.

```
require 'ruby2d'
set background: "Navy"
show
```

[Image of the error coming up in vscode terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhAhZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

After searching for the above problem on various sites,Finally my problem got resolved.

So,All the folks who would come across the same problem.
Here's the Solution

1)https://www.ruby2d.com/learn/linux/#install-packages

{ Do as it is as written in the article for the Linux users
}

2)`gem install ruby2d`

Yippe, Everything works well! After this.